# Equality involving binomial coefficient

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I think the following equality is correct, but I'm not sure, so I'm asking you:
$$\left(\prod_{\large\tfrac{n}{2}\,<\,p\,\le\,\tfrac{6n}{7}}p\right)\cdot\left(\prod_{\large n\,<\,p\,\le\,3n\strut}p\right)<\binom{3n}{\frac{n}{2}}$$ for even $ n $. 
$ p $ is a prime.

Comment: Is $p$ representative of a prime, or a generic integer?

Comment: Oh, sorry , I forgot:$ p $ is a prime ;D

Answer (score 0):

Not correct.

For $n=4$, $$1155=3\cdot (5\times 7\times 11)\color{red}{\gt} \binom{12}{2}=66.$$